# Logstash not working when run as service

Tags: logstash

I am trying to run logstash on my Debian machine. The config file is simple for testing purposes:

```
input {  
    stdin {}
}

output 
{
    file {
        path => "/tmp/test_logstash"
    }
}
```

When I run the command `sudo /etc/init.d/logstash start` I get the output `logstash started`.

Now I type some sample input in my command line such as `ls -lah`, which should be written to `/tmp/test_logstash` as configured in the config file.

But the nothing is written and when I ask about the status of logstash I get the output `logstash is not running`.

All log files in `/var/log/logstash` are empty files.

When I run `/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d` everything works fine, but I need to run it as a service in the background.

I am new to using logstash and maybe it's something very easy to solve but I couldn't find any solution yet.

It would be great if someone has a solution for this.

EDIT:
Background is that I want to install and start logstash in an ansible playbook `/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /path/to/config` the playbook hangs in there as it is waiting for the command to be finished (wich will not be the case, because you have to quit logstash with ctrl + d then). Maybe there is an easier solution for that.

EDIT 2:
The owner of `/opt/logstash` directory is the user logstash with group logstash. The init.d startup script for logstash is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could You show us logstash start script from init.d, and tell us who is the owner of /opt/logstash directory and what rights are set for this directory?

Comment: Maybe,  You can try - shell: nohup /opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /path/to/config &  on your playbook until look a solution to make a service.

Comment: @pWoz I added the Info you asked for. Sorry it took a while because I was not in the office till today and could not get the info earlier.

Comment: @RaulHugo the ansible playbook is also just hanging on startup logstash when used nohup to start logstash

Answer (score 1):

Just use this command:

```
/opt/logstash/bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d &
```

This will start the process in background.

Comment: I've had nothing but issues with this rpm.  Maybe this is the solution?  :(

Answer (score 0):

```
cat /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log
```

In my case, I ran this:

```
chmod -R 777 /var/lib/logstash
```